# Can I use the "Edit and continue" debugger tool in visual studio code?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to change your code while your program/game is running? I saw a video how it's done in visual studio but I was wondering if you can do it in vscode, and also I use c++.

Comment: Unlikely. VS Code calls out to a third-party debugger to do its debugging. There won't be the same tight integration between the IDE, debugger (and compiler) you get in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

For more general information see here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug

You would have to stop the debugger, change your code, save, and then relaunch.